# LEFT OUTER JOIN with DataSets

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset, left-join

I have the following two tables:

Department (DepartmentID (PK), DepartmentName)
Projects (ProjectID (PK), DepartmentID (FK))

And I want to create a crystal report that displays DepartmentID, DepartmentName and NoOfProjectsManagedbyDepartment

I know I can get that result using the following query:

```
SELECT d.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName, 
       Count(p.ProjectID) AS NoOfProjectsManagedByDepartment
FROM Departments d LEFT OUTER JOIN Projects p 
     ON d.DepartmentID = p.DepartmentID
GROUP BY d.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName
```

And in Crystal Reports, I use a Dataset with two DataTables for Departments and Projects.

My question is, how can I perform the LEFT OUTER JOIN on the two DataTables and display the result I want in the crystal report? Please help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have a single DataTable created from the query above? By the way, the department name should either be part of GROUP BY or, better, have an aggreation function

```
MAX(d.DepartmentName) AS DeptName
```

---

EDIT:

Outer joins are a matter of SQL queries, not a matter of DataTables.

Use the database expert found in the shorcut menu (Database > Database Expert...). Here, select the current connection (not the DataSets) and use  "Add Command". This opens a SQL query editor where you can enter the above query.

[image]

Comment: Hi Olivier, I'm actually new to Crystal Reports and I wanted to know whether the LEFT OUTER JOIN is possible in the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking for is to add a [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx) to the dataset.

```
// Fetch the columns in the relationship
var parentColumn = DataSet1.Tables["Department"].Columns["(DepartmentID"];
var childColumn = DataSet1.Tables["Projects"].Columns["(DepartmentID"];

// Create the relation
var relation = new DataRelation("ProjectsDepartments", parentColumn, childColumn);

// And add it to the dataset
DataSet1.Relations.Add(relation);
```